# How to block all texts from bit.ly?

Tags: iphone

I have started to get text messages from bit.ly on my iPhone 6. It doesn't have a number—it just says "bit.ly".

I am confused that how can something which has no number is sending me text messages. I want to block it completely and totally. No one from bit.ly should ever be able to send me a text message.

How can it be blocked?

When I open the text message and click on bit.ly, I see the following options

- send my current location
- share my location
- do not disturb

How to block bit.ly from sending me text messages?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean by there is no number sending you the text message. What do you see in the from fiend?

Comment: This might be something you'll have to go to your carrier about to get resolved. iOS only supports blocking individual numbers, not messages based off content.

Comment: bit.ly is a URL-shortening system. See their site at https://bitly.com It is unlikely to be directly responsible for whatever you are being sent

Comment: Do you have a bit.ly account setup with your phone number?

Comment: How to check? and how to remove? I have iphone 6

Comment: Please share a screencap of what you see (you can take one by pressing the home and sleep button simultaneously)

Comment: added screen capture

Comment: That looks to me like you signed-up for email or alerts or something from bit.ly and gave them your email address or phone number.  If that's true, you should be able to unsubscribe from their site.  If that doesn't work, see [this Apple Support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201229), it might help.

Comment: no I didn't. I have no account on bit.ly

Comment: I have received "bit.ly" messages as well. They appear to be SMS spam (not iMessage), as my phone shows a green send button. Like OP, the only thing I can do is leave the spam messages sit there and turn on "Do Not Disturb" for that message thread. I clicked the create new contact from the bit.ly info screen, added zeros for the phone number as indicated above, but that didn't link the bit.ly message to the new contact created. There appears to be no way to actually block these.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To block this type of call:

1. Create a new contact called something like Non-Caller, No-Caller or Bit.ly
2. Enter 000-000-0000 for the phone number.
3. Scroll down and select Block this Caller

This should stop calls from calls that come from "zero" numbers.

I just remembered this tips to block No Caller calls -> https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6040239?tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

I read the Wired article but it is out of date.....here is what I just did (for iPhone users)...go to settings/messages....scroll down and turn on Filter Unknown Senders.  It will turn off notifications from unknown senders and sort them into a different folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the blue info sign in the top right hand corner
2. Click the profile button where it has a placeholder image and bit.ly
3. "Block this Caller" will be the last option

I just got a text from them saying "Premier Investor Report". Weird…

Comment: The OP says they went to that location and 'block this caller' is not there.  Can you post images of what you're seeing?  Also what version of iOS are you running?

Answer (score 0):

your mobile carrier is the best place to block messages since they actually delivered the specific message to your specific handset. They allow caller-id to be spoofed or not and choose how to route messages.

- ask them to disable email to SMS for your account to start.
- Then use their spam reporting mechanism
- Lastly, use [Apple’s block contact and block calls feature](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201229) to block any that persist in bugging you once the main avenues in are shut

If you can't figure out the exact sending number on your device - you should get support from them to review your bill and your service details. Once you know one or two instances how spam messages are arriving - you can decide to block them, turn off SMS entirely or configure the iOS side to handle messages from numbers that are not in your contact list separately from messages from people or services you have "white listed".

The other way would be to disable iMessage for a time and focus on SMS delivery to get it cleaned out - sometimes it's hard to know which is which when both arrive in the same app.

Answer (score -1):

The only way to block this sender is via your carrier. It is with your carrier's "blessings" that this sender is spamming you, and your carrier is getting paid for this.

It happened to me a few years ago. I was getting spammed by several companies in my home country, and I traced this to my carrier. They admitted doing it, and even openly advertised it as a service for companies to reach out to potential customers. It was exactly as you describe it: instead of a phone number in the sender's field, there was a text with the name of the company, and it was impossible to reply or block the sender through the phone's settings.

I called my carrier to complain on multiple occasions, and even threatened with legal action.

Answer (score -2):

This is spam. It is not from bit.ly

When you get it via iMessages then it can be originated from a mobile number or an email address.

Try pressing (i) and then bit.ly in the description field, you should get the details and from there you will be able to block.

Comment: The info about the details was already provided by the OP in the question.  The OP wants to know how to block because they don't see that option there.

Comment: not a helpful answer because I already clicked on details. The details did not see anything else other than bitly. So I am confused as to how is someone able to imessage me. If they had a phone number I could have blocked that phone.... but in this case there is no phone number

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch i think it would be sufficient to know your email address to send an iMessage to you. You should nevertheless change your password as a precaution.

Comment: Take a look at this article https://www.wired.com/2014/08/apples-imessage-is-being-taken-over-by-spammers/.

Comment: You should report SPAM https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201229. Send a screenshot to imessage.spam@apple.com.