# Any way to block all messages from email addresses in messenger?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, sms

I frequently get spam messages sent to my iPhone messenger from email addresses. I have no idea how that is even possible. Regardless, these are *always* spam, and I would love to be able to block them *all*. Is there a way to do this?
[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

In Settings → Messages, under Message Filtering you can enable ‘Filter Unknown Senders’ which will keep them in a separate list you can switch to in Messages, sort of like a spam folder in email.

Comment: This is ok, but I still get the notification :(

Answer (score 0):

Contact your [cellular carrier](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/362632/5472) to block their email to SMS gateway. I don’t think any integrate this feature into iOS but perhaps their app for managing your account lets you DIY based on which carrier you have.

You could also try [this trick of adding zero numbers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/256287/5472) to your personal blocked contact list.